# How can I mix a populated ObjectId with a string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

Actually, in the database I got a job that I request with a GET route:

[image]

So when I populate candidates I got this response format :

[image]

**My problem here** is I don't need that "id" object, I just need a "selected_candidates" array with users inside as objects. Actually it's an object, in another object that is in an Array.

Here the code from my controller (the populate is in the jobsService):

[image]

---

If I change the data format of the job like that way:

[image]

...It is working great (with a path: "candidates_selected") like expected BUT I don't have that "status" string (Normal because I don't have it anymore in the DataBase. Because of ObjectId):

[image]

I would like a solution to have them both, but maybe it's the limit of noSQL?

---

A solution without populate but with a Loop (I don't think it's a good idea):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no convenience way to achieve it. However you may try the aggregate framework from the native MongoDB driver.

Let your Mongoose schemas be **ASchema** and **BSchema**

```
const result = await ASchema.aggregate([
    {$addFields: {org_doc: '$$ROOT'}}, // save original document to retrieve later
    {$unwind: '$candidates_selected'},
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: BSchema.collection.name,
            let: {
                selected_id: '$candidates_selected.id',
                status: '$candidates_selected.status',
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {$expr: {$eq: ['$$selected_id', '$_id']}}, // find candidate by id
                },
                {
                    $addFields: {status: '$$status'} // attach status
                }
            ],
            as: 'found_candidate'
        }
    },
    {
        $group: { // regroup the very first $unwind stage
            _id: '$_id',
            org_doc: {$first: '$org_doc'},
            found_candidates: {
                $push: {$arrayElemAt: ['$found_candidate', 0]} // result of $lookup is an array, concat them to reform the original array
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {'org_doc.candidates_selected': '$found_candidates'} // attach found_candidates to the saved original document
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$org_doc'} // recover the original document
    }
])
```